# Создание индексов

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие индексы нужно создать в таблице `docCaption` для данного запроса?

```
    select sprm.fio, d.NameDeist
, DC.Dateotch, DC.kodskl, dc.NumOtch
, sum(dc.itogotov)as sumtov
, sum(dc.itogotar) as sumtar,
 nachosttov = (
    select SUM(dc1.itogotov) 
    from doccaption as dc1 
    where (dc1.kodskl=dc.kodskl) 
        and (idgroper=(
                select idgroper 
                from tbgroper tbG 
                where   (Select
                                (Case When CharIndex(" ",NameDeist)=0 
                                     then " " 
                                    else  SubString(NameDeist,1,CharIndex(" ",NameDeist)-1) 
                                end) 
                        from tbDeist 
                        where IdNameDeist = (
                                Select IdDeistPar 
                                from tbDeist 
                                where IdNameDeist = tbG.IdNameDeist
                            ) 
                            and IdDeistPar=2 
                    ) like '41.1' 
                    and nameGrOper="Ввод остатков")
            )
)
, nachosttar = (
    select sum (dc1.itogotar) 
    from doccaption as dc1 
    where (dc1.kodskl=dc.kodskl) 
        and (idgroper = (
            select idgroper 
            from tbgroper tbG 
            where  (Select (Case When CharIndex(" ",NameDeist)=0 
                                then " " 
                                else  SubString(NameDeist,1,CharIndex(" ",NameDeist)-1) 
                            end) 
                    from tbDeist 
                    where IdNameDeist = (
                            Select IdDeistPar 
                            from tbDeist 
                            where IdNameDeist = tbG.IdNameDeist
                        ) 
                        and IdDeistPar=2
                ) like '41.1' 
                and nameGrOper="Ввод остатков")
            )
)
, prihtov = (select SUM(dc1.itogotov) 
             from doccaption as dc1 
             where (numotch is not null)
                and (dc1.numotch<dc.numotch) 
                and (dc1.datedoc<=dc.dateotch) 
                and (DC1.vidDOC=1 OR DC1.vidDOC=5)
                and (kodskl=1381)
            )
, rashtov =(select SUM(dc1.itogotov) 
            from doccaption as dc1 
            where (numotch is not null)
                and (dc1.numotch<dc.numotch) 
                and (dc1.datedoc<=dc.dateotch) 
                and (dc1.viddoc=2)
                and (kodskl=1381)
            )
, prihtar=(select sum(dc1.itogotar) 
            from doccaption as dc1 
            where (numotch is not null) 
                and (dc1.numotch<dc.numotch) 
                and (dc1.datedoc<=dc.dateotch) 
                and (DC1.vidDOC=1 OR DC1.vidDOC=5)
                and (kodskl=1381)
    )
, rashtar=(select sum(dc1.itogotar) 
            from doccaption as dc1 
            where (numotch is not null) 
                and (dc1.numotch<dc.numotch) 
                and (dc1.datedoc<=dc.dateotch) 
                and (dc1.viddoc=2)
                and (kodskl=1381)
    )
 from DocCaption dc 
 INNER JOIN tbMol sprm ON sprm.TabN=DC.TabN 
 INNER join tbGrOper op ON Dc.IdGrOper= op.IdGrOper 
 Inner join tbDeist d on d.idNameDeist=op.IdNameDeist 
 where kodskl=1381 
     and (dc.Dateotch between '16.11.2017' and '16.11.2017')
     and (DC.NumOtch is not null) 
     and (sprm.TabN=DC.TabN) 
     and (sprm.idPredpr=DC.Kodskl)
 group by sprm.fio
    ,DC.Dateotch
    ,DC.kodskl
    ,dc.NumOtch
    ,d.NameDeist 
order by dc.numotch
```

Я думаю что нужны индексы dateOtch и numOtch.

MS SQL Server 2000.

Comment: вы там слыхали вообще про подзапросы или cte, из которых можно выборки делать, а не только суммы считать? какой диалект используете? из профайлера коли взяли, то и план выполнения скиньте

Comment: Пропроще запроса не нашлось?

Comment: а как же [be nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) ?

Comment: Пока не указана СУБД и версия сервера БД, вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Я боюсь тот особо ничего не сделать. по коду склада у вас индекс и так есть, вид документа слишком не селективный. остается только дата документа ... ну т.е. единственно возможный был бы kodskl, datedoc но там условия на "меньше" и будут выбрано больше половины таблицы

Comment: @Mike dateOtch и numOtch очень помогли, теперь можно работать. Почему Вы мне в скайпе не отвечаете? Или мои сообщения не доходят?

Comment: @aaa В скайпе сообщений не вижу

Comment: @Mike Добрый день. Подскажите Ваш скайп?